# Android: Custom PagerTitleStrip, how to?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity

I'm using the pageviewer with PagerTitleStrip, and I want the titles to be like this (taken from htc):

[image]

- Non focused tabes: to be at **left** and **right** side with **semi trasparent** in half.

Currently I managed just to change the text color of focused/non focused titles:

```
private CharSequence relativeSizeSpan(CharSequence source, int pos) {
    final SpannableString ss = new SpannableString(source);
    if (viewPager.getCurrentItem() != pos) {
        ss.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(0xffa8a5a5), 0, source.length(), 0);
    }
    else {
        ss.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(0xff787777), 0, source.length(), 0);
    }
    return ss;
}
```

Comment: check this link - http://blog.pboos.ch/android-pagertabstrip-viewpager/

Answer (score 0):

Something like this below may be help. Try combine with your suggestion.

```
        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                SpannableStringBuilder sb1 = new SpannableStringBuilder(" " + str1 + (position + 1)); // space added before text for convenience

                sb1= coloredSpannable(sb1, position);

                drw1.setBounds(0, 0, drw1.getIntrinsicWidth(), drw1.getIntrinsicHeight());
                ImageSpan span1 = new ImageSpan(drw1, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE);
                sb1.setSpan(span1, 0, 1, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

                return sb1;
            case 1: 

                SpannableStringBuilder sb2 = new SpannableStringBuilder(" " + str2 + (position + 1)); // space added before text for convenience

                sb2= coloredSpannable(sb2, position);

                drw1.setBounds(0, 0, drw1.getIntrinsicWidth(), drw1.getIntrinsicHeight());
                ImageSpan span2 = new ImageSpan(drw1, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE);
                sb2.setSpan(span2, 0, 1, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

                return sb2;
            case 2: 
                SpannableStringBuilder sb3 = new SpannableStringBuilder(" " + str3 + (position + 1)); // space added before text for convenience

                sb3= coloredSpannable(sb3, position);

                drw1.setBounds(0, 0, drw1.getIntrinsicWidth(), drw1.getIntrinsicHeight());
                ImageSpan span3 = new ImageSpan(drw1, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE);
                sb3.setSpan(span3, 0, 1, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

                return sb3;

            default:
                return null;
            }

        }


private SpannableStringBuilder coloredSpannable(SpannableStringBuilder source, int pos) {
            final SpannableStringBuilder ss = source;

            if (vpPager.getCurrentItem() > pos) {
                ss.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLACK), 4, 7, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            }
            else {

            }
            if (vpPager.getCurrentItem() < pos) {
                ss.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLACK), 1, 4, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            }
            else {

            }
            return ss;
        }
```